# How to use properly linq to perform efficiently a conversion from a DataTable to a set of recursive objects?

Tags: c#, linq, design-patterns

I'm working on software dealing with tests, developping using Visual Studio 2008, C#3.5. Those tests are saved into a SQLite Database, and my software is intended to process the results. 
Well, there is a Information Table gathering the general information about the tests with the following columns:

- LayerAName
- LayerAId
- LayerBName
- LayerBId
- LayerCName
- LayerCId
- LayerDName
- LayerDId
- Start: a DateTime to indicate when the result table has been created.
- Stop: a DateTime to indicate when the result table has been modified for the last time.
- ResultTableName: this table name is used for displaying the results in a DataGridView using the VirtualMode.

The layers are discriminated using their Ids and btw, from the layer A to C, the layers are behaving like containers for gathering childlayers. Only the last layer, "layerD" is linked to a Table in the Database.

```cs
public abstract class Layer
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Stop { get; set; }
}

public class Project: Layer
{
    private Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Int32, LayerB> As { get; set; }
}

public class LayerA : Layer
{
    public Project Parent { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Int32, LayerB> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class LayerB : Layer
{
    public LayerA Parent { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Int32, LayerC> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class LayerC : Layer
{
    public LayerB Parent { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Int32, LayerB> Ds { get; set; }
}

public class LayerD : Layer
{
    public LayerC Parent { get; set; }
    public String ResultTableName { get; set; }
}
```

- Obviously if a childLayer.Start < childLayer.Parent.Start => childLayer.Parent.Start = childLayer.Start.
- The same kind of logic is used for the Stop attribute as follows: if a childLayer.Stop > childLayer.Parent.Stop => childLayer.Parent.Stop = childLayer.Stop.

Anyway, the fact is that I have already succeeded to create all the objects according to the design above but mainly by using a giant loop running through all the DataRows presents in the Information Table described previously. I also made a version using linq and DataTable as Enumerable() but both versions of my code, are to me, very dirty and hard to maintain. The difficulties are obviously mainly come from the conversion from a Table / DataTable to this set of layer objects

So I'm wondering now how to improve this...

- Is there any solution to improve this design?
- Any good pattern to use for helping?
- Is there any appropriate linqs for filtering and creating dictionaries containing the childlayers with the current Schema of the Information Table.

Thanks.

Comment: `LayerB` has a `Dictionary<Int32, LayerB>` property?is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

So why not just

```
public class ConcreteLayer: Layer
{
    public Layer Parent { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<Int32, Layer> Children{ get; set; }
}

public class FinalLayer: Layer
{
    public Layer Parent { get; set; }
    public String ResultTableName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I should re-edit what I posted, the different layers A, B, C and D have others differents attributes not related to this table. That make them different and cannot be associated, but it's true that I can create a dictionary using parent class, at the same time it loose the layer ordering (e.g like in a treeview where the node assigned to the level 0 is the Project and resp. level1 LayerA, level2 LayerB, level3 LayerC, level4 Layer.